# root element is undefined while pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui, vue-mixin

I ma using element ui el-pagination like this

```
<el-pagination
        @size-change="handleChange"
        @current-change="CurrentChange"
        :current-page.sync="currentPage"
        :page-sizes="[50, 100, 150, 300]"
        :page-size="pageSize"
        popper-class="popper"
        layout="sizes, prev, pager, next"
        :total="getTotal"
      />
```

i have the methods defined

```
CurrentChange(val) {
      this.currentPage = val;
    },
```

i have created a mixin called as pagination.js

because this pagination is used at many places, so i added some keyboard events in it like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.el-pager li.number').forEach((element, index) => {
       
        element.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
          if (e.key == 'Enter' || e.key == 'Space') {
            this.$root.CurrentChange(element.innerHTML);
          }
        });
      })
```

but i am getting undefined

i tried the console.log(this.$root) and i getting undefined, what i am missing here, i though the root has all the vue can fetch from

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the `keyup` event handler will refer to the element itself, not the component instance, you need to get `this` value ( as the component instance ) from outside the `forEach` callback function.

```
const that = this;

document.querySelectorAll('ul.el-pager li.number').forEach((element, index) => {
   
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      if (e.key == 'Enter' || e.key == 'Space') {
        that.$root.CurrentChange(element.innerHTML);
      }
    });
  })
```

Comment: it is still an issue, i tried your change but i still get undefined

Comment: Where do you add this code? in which life cycle?

Comment: i am adding the code you gave me in mixin file pagination.js

Comment: also, i consoled this outside the foreach and i see the $root but the method is still not accessible

Comment: `i am adding the code you gave me in mixin file pagination.js`, in which lifecycle do you use it?

Comment: Could you provide all the code inside `mixin`?